# django can't find url even though it is there

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I have an issue where I try to go to my redirect page and get a `NoReverseMatch` when though the URL is there? Any idea how to fix this?

I have checked that the "schema" url works and it correctly supplies the openapi schema, but the other page simply can't understand the url.

URLS:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path("schema/", SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name="schema"),
    # Optional UI:
    path("docs/", SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name="schema"), name="swagger-ui"),
]
```

Errors:
[image]

[image]

Comment: How is your `include('api.urls')` have you added a namespace there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reverse url pathing, you have to use `{% url api:schema %}`. It's specified as namespace next to `include('api.urls')` or inside app urls, just above `urlpatterns` - like `app_name = "api"`.

Comment: Thst makes sense. I'll test it out and see it it works

Comment: setting path as  suggested solved the issue, thanks!
`path("docs/", SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name="api:schema"), name="swagger-ui")`